# Wordpress Header.php, putting content between <head> tags

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, head

I assumed that in the `header.php` the `<head>` tags are where I would place my facebook open graph meta tags. But the problem is that these tags when loaded, appear in the body instead of the head. Even though in the `header.php` file I place them in the `<head>` tag. Furthermore, this seems to happen with the 'post' post type, other custom post types seem to work fine.

Do you guys have any idea on how I can have these tags appear in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

verify the correct closing of the 
        
 and make sure index.php has wp_head() and wp_footer() ,although it all depends on how your theme has been coded.